# Unable to do a json Decode on data with double quotes in Php

Tags: php, json

I have a data like this

```
     { "STORYLINE":"Shn "shan" how "}
```

I am unable to do a json_decode on this data as I have double quotes around "Shan"..How to json_decode of it?

json_decode is failing because of it

I tried add slashes and then tried removed it by using strip slashes and even tried using str_replace but nothing is working out..Is there any way around it?

Comment: Escaping the quotes should have worked fine - can you show what you had when you tried that? it should have looked something like `"Shh \"shan\" how"`.

Comment: You should try to fix it at the source, where do you get this data from.

Comment: This data is stored in DB.

Comment: Did you store it correctly? i.e. with `json_encode()`?

Comment: I can't go back and json_encode as the data is huge and I have to nearly parse 9000's urls again for correctly encoding..

Answer (score 3):

http://jsonlint.com/ is a great way to validate your JSON data.

If you place `{ "STORYLINE":"Shn "shan" how "}` it will fail however if you escape the quotes like @Marty suggested you should end up with something like this:

```
{
    "STORYLINE": "Shn \"shan\" how "
}
```

Which will validate. If you are still getting an error you probably need to check that its not failing elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is If I escape t will be something like this "STORYLINE\":Shn\"shan\"how \"

Comment: what is creating the JSON data?

Comment: From a website..I have parsed this data and someone has failed to escape when they encoded it..

Comment: It would be easier if they rectified it on their end. How did you parse it?

Comment: I parsed it using a indexer and I dont have enough time to redo the indexing again :(